# Have a different style source for each div

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a different style source for each div.
Example

```
<div src="abc.css"> A
</div>

<div src="xyz.css">B
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple stylesheets in your HTML, and then use the CSS code inside them for your divs. Here; 'div1' class is inside div1-styles.css and 'div2' class is inside div2-styles.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="div1-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="div2-styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='div1'>
       Div-1 text
    </div>
    <div class='div2'>
       Div-2 text
    </div>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First its not a good practice but even is a horrible practice.. you can just use different classes in your style file and will done the work.. but if you're insisting in that even if its not right.. you can do it using this JQuery plugin that used `scoped` attribute to achieve that

The plugin: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Comment: Use of main css file with second for exceptions is a "horrible practice"? Using unneeded plugins is good? Oh, my

Comment: Ok, what you suggest?